# Prevent Certain Items from Being Deleted in ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

So here is the code I have the allows me to delete selected items in my listbox.

```
    ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection selectedItems = new ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection(lstOutput);
    selectedItems = lstOutput.SelectedItems;

    if (lstOutput.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        for (int i = selectedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            lstOutput.Items.Remove(selectedItems[i]);
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Debe seleccionar un email");
```

The problem is that I have labels at the top that show what the output is. I also have statistics at the bottom of the page. The way the code is now, I am able to delete those, which I don't want. I am unsure of how to prevent these from being deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all the fire line is unneeded and you can merger the two first line to:

```
ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection selectedItems = lstOutput.SelectedItems;
```

now for the remove of the item that you want to keep. you can make a condition.

```
for (int i = selectedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
     if(selectedItems[i] is /*here is where you come and check if the current selected item is of the type you don't want to delete*/)
            lstOutput.Items.Remove(selectedItems[i]);
}
```

if you'll tell me what's the type of the "labels at the top" and "statistics at the bottom" i'll put it in the answer

**EDIT**

in similar to what you said you can do:

```
List<object> fixedItems = new List<object>();
fixedItems.Add(/*Your labels and statistics*/);
```

and then do

```
for (int i = selectedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
     if(fixedItems.Contains(selectedItems[i]) == false)
            lstOutput.Items.Remove(selectedItems[i]);
}
```

for the list you'll need to add

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

at the beginning of the page

Comment: Alright. Thanks. Not sure exactly what information you need. The first line will always be there. It just says like name, age, weight, etc, characteristics about the person. And then there are 3 lines at the end that are the statistics that say compute the average, highs, and lows.

Comment: @user2781018 their types. what are their types?

Comment: Would it just be easier to give names of these computed lines? And then in the part of your code where I specify what they are, I just put those names I assigned those lines?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by what are their types

Comment: @user2781018 that wouldn't work, but in similarity to that look at my edit

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It didn't work. For your example, it says for List<object> that the type or namespace could not be found. I'm guessing I need to add something for that, but not sure what. Not a very experienced programmer.

Comment: Thanks. Now, selectedItems says it doesn't exist in the current context. I would declare it, but I'm not sure how you are using it.

Comment: @user2781018 this is a scope issue. i think you went a bit over your head with this task. declare the task in the class. if you don't know what that's means share the entire page and i'll edit it for you and explain

Comment: I removed the first line of the code that included the declaration of selectedItems, because you didn't put that in your edit code. I should have seen that though. My fault. Looks like it is working though. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @user2781018 glad to be of service